# Can this asphalt driveway be repaired?

Tags: driveway, asphalt

We had an asphalt driveway put down around 5-6 months ago. The second half of the driveway the mix went dry and left a bad finish. We pointed out the worst parts, the contractors came back and put two big patches over the top!! They literally stick out like you know what... We did not ask the contractors to come back but now we are wondering how to fix it. Can asphalt patches be cut out and repaired to a smooth finish that will blend back with the original asphalt? Remember this a driveway not a road!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good rental yard will have a "walk behind" surface grinder with which you could grind the surface level. Then you could resurface the whole thing with a liquid slurry asphalt resurfacing material, it will look uniform and new when you are done. Or... you could hire a **reputable** contractor to do it for you.

[image][image]

Pictures stolen shamelessly from the internet.

Comment: That's great, thanks. Is it a specific asphalt surface grinder you need? How exactly does a liquid slurry asphalt resurfacing work?

Comment: I can see on youtube how liquid asphalt resurfacing material is applied but don't fully understand it's purpose. Is it supposed to be like a protective coating? I would imagine it dries very hard like the original asphalt?

Comment: It is liquefied asphalt but with little or no aggregate (rocks/sand). if your existing asphalt surface is fairly smooth, you get the stuff with no aggregate; if it is rough, you get the stuff with a bit of aggregate and it will help fill in a bit of the "roughness". You use a special brush/squeegee tool to apply, it's almost like asphalt paint. it seals, resurfaces, and beautifies old asphalt driveways. A concrete grinder will work on asphalt, just do not be too aggressive with it.